# How do I fill a Datatable with results from a stored procedure? via grabbing data from a listbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable

I have been having an issue populating gridview by fill a DataTable object with results from a stored procedure.

here is my code:

```
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();
                sql.Connection = Conn;
                sql.CommandText = "usp_CalcByProgFY_Weighted";
                sql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FiscalYear", ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()));

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                Conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = sql;
                da.Fill(dt);
                GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                GridView2.DataBind();
```

I keep getting this error: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: A field or property with the name 'FiscalYear' was not found on the selected data source

Comment: what's the issue?   You're missing some key details.  Can you edit your question to provide current result and expected result along with any error messages?  Really anything that will help provide more context to your problem.

Comment: I keep getting this error:                                                                       An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A field or property with the name 'FiscalYear' was not found on the selected data source.

Comment: A couple of simple questions for you: Are you certain that your parameter is named "@FiscalYear" in the stored procedure? If so, have you confirmed that your SP executes without issue from SSMS?

Comment: @CriticalError Yes, I checked to make sure that the parameter is "@FiscalYear". I have solved the issue now. you guys are awesome. The suggestion definitely helped me to double check things.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, maybe this:

```
ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Should be this:

```
ListBox2.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps what you need is SqlDataAdapter

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_CalcByProgFY_Weighted",connection))
using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    command.Type = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FiscalYear", ListBox2.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()));
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}


GridView2.DataSource = dt;
GridView2.DataBind();
```